# Minimizing a unary quotient over a box

Tags: optimization

I'd like to find a method to solve the problem
$$\min \Biggl\{ \frac{x^2+b_1x+c_1}{x^2+b_2x+c_2}:\quad  0\leq x\leq \bar{x}
 \Biggr\}$$
where the variable $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is bounded on $[0,\bar{x}]$ and the quotient is supposed to be well defined on this box. It seems that we should be able to find a closed-form solution by discussing the coefficients. Hoping to get an answer to this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Share what you tried.

Comment: @AnneBauval I tried the one in my answer. Hope it is fine, and welcome any better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured out a way which maybe a best one as follows:
Let $$\varphi(x) = \frac{x^2+b_1x+c_1}{x^2+b_2x+c_2}$$
whose derivative is
$$\varphi'(x) = \frac{(b_2-b_1)x^2 + 2(c_2-c_1)x + b_1c_2-c_1b_2}{(x^2+b_2x + c_2)^2}.$$
Clearly, $\varphi'$ is well defined on $[0,\bar{x}]$ since the denominator never being zero on this box (by assumption).

Hence, all roots of $\varphi'$ are exactly the roots of the polynomial
$$(b_2-b_1)x^2 + 2(c_2-c_1)x + b_1c_2-c_1b_2,$$
which can be very easily computed by roots formula.

Now, let $Z$ be all real roots of this polynomial containing in the box $[0,\bar{x}]$, and let
$$C = \{0,\bar{x}\}\cup Z.$$
Clearly, all minimum of $\varphi$ over $[0,\bar{x}]$ must be included in $C$. So we just need to check all values of $\varphi$ on $C$ (with at most $4$ different values) and take their minima.